# How to use Zend paginate without loading all the results of a db?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

I am relatively new to The Zend framework having only been working with it probably 1 month. I have a query that's running way too slow. The page takes a few minutes to load. In my query, is it grabbing all the records or is it getting only the amount I need for the page?Can I apply a limit in fetching the contents from the DB?

My code is as follows.

```
public function init() {
  $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employee ';
  $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
  $page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
  $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
  $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
  $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
  $this->view->paginator=$paginator;        
}
```

I will be greatful for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are supplying a Db query to your Paginator factory, Paginator will in most cases use the DbSelect Paginator adapter. This adapter will make the smallest query possible to satisfy the demands on the Paginator.

To make sure the Paginator uses the correct adapter you can pass a string as the second arg.

`$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result, 'DbSelect');`

Excerpt from Reference:

> **Note:**  Instead of selecting every matching row of a given query, the
>   DbSelect and DbTableSelect adapters retrieve only the smallest amount
>   of data necessary for displaying the current page.
>
> Because of this, a second query is dynamically generated to determine
>   the total number of matching rows. However, it is possible to directly
>   supply a count or count query yourself. See the setRowCount() method
>   in the DbSelect adapter for more information.

if you use database profiling you can see where the limit and offset queries are generated.

**Note:**

In most instances Zend_Db will convert SQL select queries into Zend_Db_Select objects. If you find you are in one of the rare situations where this is not the case you will either need to use the array adapter for Paginator or refactor your sql as a Zend_Db_Select object. This should be very rare.

Also it is rather unusual to see a paginator instance in the init() method. The init() will be run on every request to that controller.